# How can I position a Google chart in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am using Google chart. The positioning eludes me. I haven't located that part in the documentation. I simply want to create a Google chart inside a div with the top left corner positioned in (x, y) in the div. Extra points for help with controlling the dimensions.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I look in the html in 'runtime' using a tool like firebug I see:

```
rect x="161" y="96" width="579" height="309"
```

But I did not pick any of those values.

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and added some :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For example to position the chart at (0,0) within the DIV, add to the chart options :

```
var options = {
          ...,
          chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"50%",height:"50%"}
}
```

and adjust the width and height as you want; the full options are [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Configuration_Options).

Answer (score 2):

OK, you need to add some extra HTML:

```
<body>
    <div style="position:relative;width:100%">
        <div id="chart_div" style="position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The height of the chart can be controlled by the width and height of the div. The placement can be controlled by changing, right, top, of changing to left/bottom, etc.

You may want to float the chart_div, or use any other method of positioning.

Depending on your requirements, this may be enough: If not, let me know.